How to mount a RFM69HCW RF tranceiver on perf board?
I bought this RFM69HCW RF tranceiver from Sparkfun without realizing that there's a version with the breakout board! The holes on the version I bought are too close to each other such that the 0.1 male headers I use to mount them through-hole on perf boards.
Is there anyway I can mount this on a perf board (or bread board) using some kind of male headers?


RFM69HCW ISM TRANSCEIVER MODULE v 1.1 on the Sparkfun site contains Figure 41. S 2 Package Outline Drawing:



The units are not shown, but I assume are in millimetres. Therefore the vertical pin pitch is 2 millimetres.
A pair of adapters such as Lazmin 10Pcs 1.27MM 2.0MM 2.54MM Adapter Plate Board 8PIN for Wireless Modules could used to convert the eight rows of 2.0 mm pitch on the RFM69HCW board to 2.54 mm (0.1 inch) pitch:



(the above is from Amazon, on a quick search didn't find anything from a reputable distributor)
With two adapters attached to the RFM69HCW board I'm not sure what the horizontal spacing would be between the rows of pins, but could probably bend to fit in a perf board with 0.1 inch spacing.
